# ExtJS turning off field validation onkeyup

Tags: extjs

I have an ExtJS combobox, which is a required field, but I don't want the required field error message to show up until I try to submit the form.  Right now, it is happening on keyup it seems like.  I have set validateOnBlur to false, but it still shows up.  I am specifying a vtype though, 'required", and it still seems to firing the validate event on the control and therefore the vtype gets called.  I don't want the validate to fire until I manually call it.  Any help?  Here is some code:

```
var ddl = new TaskCombo({
    id: 'ddl' ,
    fieldLabel: 'test',
    tabIndex: 1,
    selectOnFocus: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    disabled: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    validateOnBlur:false,
    vtype: 'required',
    vtypeText:'This is a required field test',
    msgTarget: 'under',
    store: new TestStore});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `validationEvent:false` ([docs](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Field.html#cfg-Ext.form.Field-validationEvent)).

Comment: Sorry, I literally found this after I posted.  Thanks a lot though, you have been a huge help so far with all of my questions.

Comment: As for 2015 - use validateOnBlur, validateOnChange instead.